# "В частности" в конце предложения.

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в таком предложении?
Я, конечно, не отрицаю некого воздействия и на меня(,) в частности, что печально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужна. Логическое ударение падает на это слово: что-то в общем, а это в частности.Это как бы общая конструкция, как и в присоединении:Я тоже привык записывать свои мысли на чём попало, в частности на папиросных коробках. К. Паустовский, Золотая роза. Вот ответ Грамоты.ру: В конструкции «...вообще и ...в частности» знаки препинания не требуются.
Думал о вас, о привлекательности вообще и вашей в частности. И. Ефремов, Лезвие бритвы.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_132

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не "вообще и в частности", а другой случай.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ